# #<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: book>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

this is my controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController 
 def create
   @book = Book.new(book_params)
   if @book.save
     render json: @book, status: 201
   else
    render json: { error: "check attributes again", status: 400 }, status: 400
   end
  end
 private

 def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:author, :categories, :publisher, :title)
 end
end
```

i am passing prams like this

```
{  "book":{
      "author": "some one",
      "categories": "some thing",
      "publisher": "some publisher",
      "title": "some thing my own"
      }
}
```

I am getting the above error what is the wrong in it. Any ideas? I am using `sqlite3` data base and `webric` server.

Comment: Are you sure you receive exactly such format of params? Check them in webric logs after exception.

Comment: try using this `params.fetch(:book, {}).permit(:author, :categories, :publisher, :title)`

Comment: can you please explain where i can find webric logs??  i am new to this. @BorisPilgun

Comment: it saving default values when i tried like that @Sravan

Comment: About Logs: look into the log folder of your rails project.

Comment: @Nani like was said above you can find logs in your `log/development.log` or if you're running webrick from console using comand `rails server` you should be able to see logs right there if default settings not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check below log file.

"your rails directory"/logs/development.log

And one more point, you should write 'puts' debug like below, because 'puts' results display above log file.

```
def create
 puts 'params => ' + params
 @book = Book.new(book_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nani, you have to find in your logs something similar to this:

```
Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 18:58:17 +0200
Processing by BooksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"....", "book"=>{....}}
```

And here you need to check if you expecting correct parameters in your controller.